# How to create custom resolution

Tags: resolution

How do I input custom resolution in the nvdidia xserver settings? I need to make the output 1804x1014.

I am not familiar with the cryptic command prompts but really need this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your resolution using `nvidia-xconfig --mode=1804x1014` or try to manually edit `xorg.conf`.

Details can be found in `man xorg.conf` or in Nvidia's documentation.